# Access a WPF TreeViewItem in C# on a double click

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I want to access a WPF TreeViewItem on a double click. In my WPF it looks like this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="ExerciseTreeView" Background="#FFF9F9F9" MouseDoubleClick="Exercise_MouseDoubleClick" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  Grid.Column="2" />
```

In my C# Code I add the TreeViewItems like this (I have some tasks for a physiotherapy in the lists):

```
RumpfItem.Header = "Rumpf";

ObereItem.Header = "Obere Extremität";

UntereItem.Header = "Untere Extremität";

DehnenItem.Header = "Dehnen";

FaszienItem.Header = "Faszientraining";



foreach(var item in Model.Categories_List)
{
  Task task = Model.Task_List.First(t => t.TaskID == item.TaskID);

  if (item.CategoryID == 1)
  {
    RumpfItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = task.Name });
  }
  if (item.CategoryID == 2)
  {
    ObereItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = task.Name });
  }
  if (item.CategoryID == 3)
  {
    UntereItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = task.Name });
  }
  if (item.CategoryID == 4)
  {
    DehnenItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = task.Name });
  }
    if (item.CategoryID == 5)
  {
    FaszienItem.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header = task.Name });
  }
  }
  ExerciseTreeView.Items.Add(RumpfItem);
  ExerciseTreeView.Items.Add(ObereItem);
  ExerciseTreeView.Items.Add(UntereItem);
  ExerciseTreeView.Items.Add(DehnenItem);
  ExerciseTreeView.Items.Add(FaszienItem);
  OpenTrainingPlan_Tab();
```

It shows up correctly but when I do a double click on a TreeViewItem nothing happens. So how can I access the Task I clicked on in my C# Code?

Comment: You are attaching an event handler to the `TreeView` but it sounds like you really want to attach one to `TreeViewItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by setting the event to each item. This can be done by setting the style of your items like:

```
<TreeView x:Name="MyTreeView">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                         Handler="HandleItemDoubleClick"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Let's say you have a tree view with minimal item like

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

with some items inside:

```
MyTreeView.Items.Add(new Item { Name = "1" });
MyTreeView.Items.Add(new Item { Name = "2" });
```

Then you are able to access the clicked item in a handler like:

```
private void HandleItemDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((TreeViewItem)sender).DataContext is Item item)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
    }
}
```